# CUFFT with double precision

Tags: cuda, fft, double-precision, cufft

I am experiencing some problems with CUDAs FFT library.

I declared the inputs as cuDoubleComplex, but the compiler returns the error that this type is incompatible with parameters of type cufftComplex. After some search through the Internet, I found the file cufft.h, in which there is the line `typedef cuComplex cufftComplex;`. My problem is that in the library cuComplex.h it is clear that cuComplex has a single floating point precision (`typedef cuFloatComplex cuComplex;`), but I would like a double precision.

Is this possible?

In particular, I obtain the following:

```
error: argument of type "cufftDoubleComplex *" is incompatible with parameter of type "cufftComplex *"
```

at this line:

```
cufftExecC2C(plan, data1, data2, CUFFT_FORWARD);
```

Comment: What function call is producing the compilation error? CUFFT has an explicit `cufftDoubleComplex` type and `CUFFT_D2Z`, `CUFFT_Z2D`, and `CUFFT_Z2Z` operations for double-to-double complex, double complex-to-double, and double complex-to-double-complex calls. You have not made it at all clear where the problem is occurring.

Comment: When I try to compile the code with nvcc, I obtain the error `error: no suitable user-defined conversion from "cuComplex" to "cuDoubleComplex" exists`

Comment: yes, but *where* in the code you aren't showing. What operation or function call produces the error?

Comment: With your suggestions, I tried to implement `cufftDoubleComplex`, but I obtain `error: argument of type "cufftDoubleComplex *" is incompatible with parameter of type "cufftComplex *"` Maybe there are some problems with my installation of CUDA; otherwise, which header should I use? (Currently I have only `#include <cufft.h>`). Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Sorry, it's here that I obtain the error: `cufftExecC2C(plan, ms, ms, CUFFT_FORWARD);`

Comment: Use `cufftExecZ2Z` instead of `cufftExecC2C`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was sure I was making a stupid mistake. :)

Comment: @Pippo: It would be helpful for the next person that comes along if you edit the relevant with the compilation problem into your question for future reference, then accept sgar91's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The double precision complex data type is defined as `cufftDoubleComplex` in CUFFT.

Double precision versions of fft in CUFFT are:

```
cufftExecD2Z() //Real To Complex

cufftExecZ2D() //Complex To Real

cufftExecZ2Z() //Complex To Complex
```

`cufftExecC2C` is the single precision version of fft, and expects the input and output pointers to be of type `cufftComplex`,whereas you are passing it a pointer of type `cufftDoubleComplex`.

For `cufftDoubleComplex` data type, you have to use the function `cufftExecZ2Z` instead, which is for double precision data.